# Who are all these people in the Admiral's Club?

Tags: air-travel, airports, american-airlines

I usually have tight enough connections that I don't have time to go to the Admiral's Club. It's a once or twice a year thing for me, not often enough to justify the $550 cost. Yet, every time I go in the place always has a lot of occupants. Are these (1) mostly people who just fly so much that it is worth the money for the membership? Or, (2) are there special deals and tricks that people use to get membership for a lot less (kind of like the "priority" security line)? Or, (3) is Admiral Club membership expensable at a lot of companies, so it is not costing them anything at all? (it is certainly not expensable where I work)

Comment: Any demographics on Admirals Club usage or membership is likely to be closely held proprietary information. As such, the only answers we can give will be speculative, which Stack Exchange tends to frown upon. I have to say, however, that $550 for an entire year is a pretty trivial expense for a business traveler, one that could pay for itself with a single visit to the agents in the club. Membership is also significantly discounted for frequent flyers and credit card holders, which you can see for yourself easily enough.

Comment: I had access through a program my company participated in called AAirpass.  You can also get access if you have certain types of credit cards and I know if you reached a certain level at a different company I worked at they would give you that card.

Comment: 1) Yes, when I arrive early or have a delay.  2) Yes, F/J fares and credit cards + one day passes.  3) Yes.

Comment: I have a few friends who travel regularly for work - international flight twice per week will give you a lot of loyalty points to spend on various perks/

Comment: And many memberships allow you to bring one or more guests, and staff sometimes use the place to rest as well, so the number of paying customers is actually lower than the number of people there.

Comment: My partner and I both travel for work 2-3 times a week and so we are one world Emerald members -> access to admiral club. The people I see are generally business people who travel a lot for work...

Comment: @choster Any Admirals Club member or user could answer with their observations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Admirals Club access](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/clubs/admirals-club-access.jsp) page, you'll see that there are a number of ways you can get access to the lounge. A membership is one of them, and the cost goes down with higher tiers of AAdvantage status. The membership is also included as part of certain credit cards' annual fees or can even be purchased with miles. Some companies may purchase memberships for their employees and executives, and memberships may be included as part of a company's special contract with an airline they use regularly. If you fly dozens of times a year on business and need to maximize your working time, the value of the membership is easier to justify. People may also have access to other lounges through their credit cards, [Priority Pass](https://www.prioritypass.com/), and other schemes.

But many people have access through other mechanisms. Anyone in first or business class on American or a oneworld airline for international and US transcon flights has lounge access, as do AAdvantage Platinum and higher members on all international flights. oneworld Emerald and Sapphire members with status from an airline other than American have access on all American and oneworld flights. And people can buy one-time day passes.

Those groups cover a lot of people who don't have memberships. Just the first and business class passengers on international flights will be a good number of lounge visitors. Not all of them are members.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. I notice that Priority Pass offers 10 free visits for $250 and unlimited visits for $400 which is less that the AA membership, so why would anyone do AA for $550 when they can get unlimited PP for $400?

Comment: @LemuelGulliver Priority Pass is only accepted at certain lounges, and they might not be ones you want to or can visit, especially if most of your flying is US domestic. For example, the only lounge they have at SFO is the AF/KLM lounge, which is out in the international A gates and useless to most travelers. At LAX, you get a lounge in the international terminal and one in Terminal 6, but none anywhere else. It's a good deal for some people (and PP access is sometimes included with credit cards), but you really have to look at where the lounges are and whether they're useful to you.

Comment: Ah ha, yes, it seems most of their lounges are in the International terminals, so domestic travelers get no benefits unless they want to hoof it to that terminal.

Comment: +1, best answer on the airports tag this year!

Comment: @LemuelGulliver Priority Pass' lounge coverage in the U.S. is kind of bad. Lots of U.S. airports, even some major ones, don't have any PP lounges at all. They are getting better, though. Its primary use is for when traveling outside of the U.S. where the lounges you normally use in the U.S. don't exist. For example, with AmEx Platinum Card, you get access to AmEx's lounges, Delta's lounges when flying Delta, and all PP lounges. So, the AmEx Centurion lounges and Delta SkyClubs cover the U.S. pretty well, while PP has good overseas coverage.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, access to Delta's SkyClub lounges is almost exactly the same as what Zach described here for American's Admiral's Clubs, except that you can also get into Delta's lounges with the Platinum Card if you're flying Delta. This used to be possible with the Citi Prestige card on American, but that ended recently.

Comment: @LemuelGulliver a bit off top maybe, but I'm very confused with your words "10 free visits for $250". What did you mean?